# Passing overloaded CRTP class member method to lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, overloading, crtp

Consider this:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_t
{
    auto& f(int x) { return (T&)*this; }
    auto& f(char x) { return (T&)*this; }
};

struct derived_t : base_t<derived_t>
{

};

void test()
{
    derived_t instance;

    auto lambda = [&](derived_t&(derived_t::*g)(char))
    {
        (instance.*g)('a');

        //instance.f('a');
    };

    lambda(&derived_t::f);
}
```

Without commenting in that particular line ( `//instance.f('a');` ) , I get the following error (MSVC 2019):

```
error C2664: 'void test::<lambda_1>::operator ()(derived_t &(__cdecl derived_t::* )(char)) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'overloaded-function' to 'derived_t &(__cdecl derived_t::* )(char)'
```

When the line isn't commented out, it compiles just fine.

Why does referencing `f` inside `lambda` magically allow the compiler to convert this overloaded function?

Furthermore, without CRTP, this doesn't happen at all.

Edit: Additionally, as pointed out by @Jarod42,

- Being explicit on return type auto& -> T& solves the issue.
- If you use a named function instead of a lambda, the problem disappears. So apparently the interaction of lambdas and templates is relevant.

Comment: Clang accepts both, gcc acts as msvc... [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b889Tq).

Comment: Being explicit on return type `auto&` -> `T&` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3f9v9T) solves issue for gcc and msvc.

Comment: Does `return *static_cast<T*>(this);` affect the outcome?

Comment: members of template are instantiated only when *required*, so explicit call of `f` instantiate it, if you use the other overload, gcc/msvc still fail [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jj9cbT). That would explain gcc/msvc behavior.

Comment: Asking for reference should instantiate it, but not sure how `auto` interact with that (we might see `auto` as template function)...

Comment: @Eljay: I provide demo link similar to OP code, if you want to play with variation.

Comment: Based on a few pages from cppreference.com and some experiments, I am currently inclined to think this is a compiler bug, but there are some details on which I would defer to a [tag:language-lawyer] working from the actual C++ specs (instead of the distilled version in cppreference.com). If it is a compiler bug, your question asks why the bug does not manifest with a certain line present, which would mean delving into the internals of the compilers. Is this what you intended to ask? Maybe you want to primarily ask if the compiler is correct in issuing this error, and why?

Comment: @JaMiT Well, I have no idea whether it is a bug or not, or what it even is at all.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO I don't have an answer, just suggestions. You can, of course, choose how you want to proceed. Sometimes bounties are a useful way to attract good answers to your question. Sometimes reformulating the question from another perspective works better.

Comment: I forgot to add an observation to the mix: if you use a named function instead of a lambda, the problem disappears. So apparently the interaction of lambdas and templates is relevant.

Comment: My guess is that this is [temp.point], and that your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic (NDR) required, due to specifically [\[temp.point\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8): _"[...] If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."_. ...

Comment: ... [CWG issue 993](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#993) added that the end of the translation unit is a point of instantiation so that implementers could make the quite straightforward choice of always deferring instantiations to the end of the TU’s, and not having to bother (no diagnostic required) about whether the program is actually ill-formed due to an uncareful developer. My experience is that different compilers implement their points of instantiations differently, often being the root cause of differing behaviour in ill-formed NDR programs.

Answer (score 3):

The template mechanism instantiates classes and functions as they are used.
The same mechanism is used to evaluate the types behind the keyword `auto`.

In your case, the return types of your `base_t<T>::f` functions are `auto&`, and require a function call to be computed.
Therefore when you comment out your only call to it (`instance.f('a');`) the actual signature of the function cannot be computed, and the compiler cannot tell whether it can be converted to `derived_t&(derived_t::*g)(char)`.

Commenting out `instance.f('a');` is possible if you define `base_t<T>::f` functions as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_t
{
    T& f(int) { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
    T& f(char) { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
};
```

Here types are deduced at instantiation of the specialized type `base_t<derived_t>` instead of at the call of the `f` functions, so the compiler can figure out its conversion to the function type `derived_t&(derived_t::*g)(char)` without having to call them in your code.

Comment: I thought computation of the return types would require instantiation, not specifically a function call. There is [an example of cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction) showing that taking the address of a function template causes return types to be computed. This is not a perfect match to `&derived_t::f`, though; which of the differences removes the requirement to compute the return type?

Comment: Their closest example is `template<typename T> auto g(T t) { return t; }`. There, it is the function that is templated, so it necessarily requires an explicit reference, such as a call, to be instantiated. In this question, it is the class that is instantiated. I just unrolled what I knew about template deduction to come to my conclusion, but I do not know what the standard really says about this case. It looks like GCC and MSVC embraced that naive approach, whereas Clang did something smarter. Both are ok until the standard specifies this case.

Comment: If you comment both lines in the lambda and add some dependent name garbage in `f` (e.g. `T t; t.i;`), you can see that clang complains about the non-existing member `i`. Thus, at line `lambda(&derived_t::f);`, it seems to decide to instantiate all `f` overloads, while the other compilers are still complaining about overload resolution...

Comment: @VictorPaléologue The cppreference example I was looking at is one that takes the address of a function template, specifically `void g() { int (*p)(int*) = &f; } // instantiates both fs to determine return types` (where the `f`s are function templates specifying `auto` as their return types). This code triggers template instantiation without needing a function call.